# Using bulk insert for 2000 rows of data

Tags: sql-server-2008, bulkinsert

Would using bulk insert for 2000 rows of data make sense?

It might be 500-2K in reality.

BTW, does bulk inserts ignore constraint or is that a setting?

(using sql server 2008, .net on the server side, data is coming in via a web service (wse or WCF)).

Comment: duplicate, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642724/fastest-way-to-bulk-insert-rows-into-sql-server

!From the same author!

Answer (score 2):

Bulk insert would probably not make sense for 2000 rows. Maybe for 200,000 rows.

Ignoring constraints is [default behaviour](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186247.aspx). (Also described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx)).

> `CHECK_CONSTRAINTS`
>
> Specifies that all constraints on the
>   target table or view must be checked
>   during the bulk-import operation.
>   Without the CHECK_CONSTRAINTS option,
>   any CHECK and FOREIGN KEY constraints
>   are ignored, and after the operation,
>   the constraint on the table is marked
>   as not-trusted.
>
> **Note:**   UNIQUE, PRIMARY KEY, and NOT NULL constraints are always
>   enforced.

The "`KEEPIDENTITY`" option of "`BULK INSERT`":

> Specifies that identity value or
>   values in the imported data file are
>   to be used for the identity column. If
>   KEEPIDENTITY is not specified, the
>   identity values for this column are
>   verified but not imported and SQL
>   Server automatically assigns unique
>   values based on the seed and increment
>   values specified during table
>   creation.

Comment: so for a PK autoincrement column, we have to update the counter manually somehow?